# How to improve the performance of the query in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a search screen in the UI, we need to search based on first name, last name, surname, state, city, dateofbirth, father name, here user can search on one column or combinations of these columns.

Right now the query is written where I used like conditions on all these columns to get the data.

But the table contains around 200000 rows, and searching based on this really decrease the performance. How can I create an nonclustered index here?

How can I improve the performance of the query, what can be done here?

Any suggestions here are welcome.

Thanks
Kumee.

Comment: Please add the table and the query...

Comment: To give a proper answer, we really need to see how you are using LIKE.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a [full text index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Comment: For a straight = search, maybe not. We can't say because there is bugger all information to go on...

Comment: @gbn, he says he is using a like condition on all the columns which can't really be optimized any other way i'm aware of.

Comment: FTS is the way forward if leading wildcards are used or full word searchs. A stem search with only trailing wildcard on a name column can use an index efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

you can use of this script :

```
CREATE INDEX IndexName on TableName (Comma Seperated Columns Name)
```

Like :

```
CREATE INDEX IX_SearchBasicInfo on BasicInfo (FirstName,LastName,SurName)
```